# Manually alpha blending an RGBA pixel with an RGB pixel

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, image-manipulation, alphablending, alpha-transparency

I am trying to do an alpha blend operation of an RGBA image (foreground image), on to a RGB image (background image). However, while doing so I think I may be doing the wrong alpha blending operation or doing it wrong. For example, the pixel of my RGB image is a grayish color of (127, 127, 127). The pixel of my RGBA image for the pixel will be (0, 0, 255). After I do my blending operation, the final color will be (127, 0, 255). However, I thought that was more of an additive blend and different than the operation I am doing.

For how my values are set, take a look at this

```
incPixelColor[0] = 0; (red)
incPixelColor[1] = 0; (green)
incPixelColor[2] = 255; (blue)
incPixelColor[3] = 255; (alpha)

currentPixelColor[0] = 127; (red)
currentPixelColor[1] = 127; (green)
currentPixelColor[2] = 127; (blue)
```

For how my calculation is set, take a look at this

```
float incAlpha = (currentPixelColor[3]/255.0f);

float red = ((float)incPixelColor[0]/255.0f * incAlpha) + ((float)currentPixelColor[0]/255.0f);
float green = ((float)incPixelColor[1]/255.0f * incAlpha) + ((float)currentPixelColor[1]/255.0f);
float blue = ((float)incPixelColor[2]/255.0f * incAlpha) + ((float)currentPixelColor[2]/255.0f);


currentPixelColor[0] = min(red * 255, 255.0f);
currentPixelColor[1] = min(green * 255, 255.0f);
currentPixelColor[2] = min(blue * 255, 255.0f);
```

For pixels with no alpha, I would like for the value to be (0, 0, 255) then for images with alpha I would like for it to blend in. At the end of the operation above, it will be (127, 127, 255). Should I check to see if there is alpha for every pixel, and if so, then do the blend or is there another way to do this?

Comment: You're doing additive blending. Consider linear mixing like this: y = (x0 * w) + (x1 * (1-w))

Comment: That's a lot of 255 scaling back and forth.  It should not be necessary if your operations maintain normalization.

Comment: Please check my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73498765/2299100

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A typical "Over" blend is done in the following way:

```
outputRed = (foregroundRed * foregroundAlpha) + (backgroundRed * (1.0 - foregroundAlpha));
```

And then repeating for the blue and green channels. Do this for every pixel.

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but isn't that what I am already doing?

Comment: No, what you're doing is outputRed = (foreRed * foreAlpha) + backgroundRed. You need to multiply the backgroundRed by the (1.0 - foreAlpha).

Comment: Sorry that so late, but what happens to the alpha output alpha channel if both destination and source pixels are transparent?

Comment: It ends up transparent, too. So if you have a source pixel with 0% coverage (alpha), it shouldn't contribute to the output. If you overlay that on a pixel with 0% coverage, the background also shouldn't contribute to the output. So the result will be RGBA = (0,0,0,0). It will be "transparent black" so to speak. If you overlay the result on something that's not transparent, you'll see whatever you overlaid it on.

Comment: Does this assume that foregroundAlpha is in the 0-255 range or 0-1 range?

Comment: It assume alpha is in the 0-1 range.

Comment: This formular makes a 50% red on white background into a `rgb(255, 128, 128)` which is mathematically correct. Under macOS I notice Chrome, Safari and even Sketch App blend that setup into `rgb(255, 138, 138)`. Firefox `rgb(255, 126, 124)`. Photoshop sticks to the 128 though. So interestingly some software takes extra steps for whatever reasons and 50% red is not universally 50% red Pen: https://codepen.io/timohausmann/pen/rNLdpwJ?editors=0100 macOS Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/2ioPPiy

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have missed out (1-Alpha) multiplier for background (currentPixelColor)