# Sum of two colors, one with alpha

Tags: android, android-layout, graphics, bitmap

I am trying to sum two colors.

Imagine a ImageView with picture and view with transparent color over that iv like filter.

How to get result of bitmap's pixel and overlapping color?

Comment: Do you want to [blend them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014729/manually-alpha-blending-an-rgba-pixel-with-an-rgb-pixel)?

Comment: Yes I want. Just like color + color, but colors like #80ff0000 with #ff123456

Comment: I actually need that result of those colors.