# Unexpected alpha blending result in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, alphablending, rgba

```
<body style="background-color:rgb(0,0,0)">
  <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)">
    rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(0, 127, 0)">
    rgb(0, 127, 0)
  </div>  
</body>
```

Here is a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/sifirebuxa/edit?html,css,output

Screenshot of what I see (Chrome Version 109 Mac OS X):
[image]

I expected the two divs to have equal colors. But I can see visually and verify with color-picker tools that they do not match in my browser.

I've read in many places that alpha blending works via the formula:
`mix(c1, c2, a) = c1*(1-a) + c2*a` But based on this experiment, this does not seem to be true in modern browsers.

My color-picker (gimp) tells me that the rendered rgb color of the top div is `rgb(19, 128, 13)`. I find this quite surprising: why would mixing green with black cause red and blue to increase, and why would they increase by differing amounts?

Can anyone explain the calculation that would result in `rgb(19, 128, 13)`?

In Firefox, the colors appear much much closer, perhaps identical.

Comment: The amount of light which comes through depends on the order in which the elements are stacked (if you put a solid black one over a semi transparent green one you see nothing but black) so I don't see how your formula works if you are interpreting a as 0.5 (if not, what is it?). Now, running your code: on my system in Chrome I notice a slight difference which I would expect (and GIMP tells me the Gs differ slightly). But I'd expect that because 127 is not half of 255. If I use 254 instead then the Gs are identical. No idea how you got R and B. How are you showing GIMP the colors to select?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say, I get the same results on Firefox and Chrome/Edge (Windows 10). with the first color having G = 254 then the resulting colors of both according to GIMP have G = 127.

Comment: Hi thanks for trying it. By `mix(c1,c2,a)` I am assuming `c1` is the foreground, `a` is its alpha value, and `c2` is a solid background color. The way I'm using Gimp is to take a screenshot (PNG) and open it with Gimp, then use its color picker. It's a good idea to change 255 to 254, but it doesn't change the result for me. Gimp tells me the top bar is `rgb(16, 128, 13)`. Btw I'm guessing you are not on a Mac? It might be a Mac-only issue based on Ti Hausmann's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014729/manually-alpha-blending-an-rgba-pixel-with-an-rgb-pixel?rq=1).

Comment: I am on Windows 10 on a laptop.