# Alpha blending with two transparent images

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, graphics

I am trying the alpha blending with two images both have alpha channel in OpenCV.

```
double r, g, b, a; //source image colors
double Rd, Gd, Bd, Ad; //destination image colors

....

double result_r = r∗a + Rd*(1−a);
double result_g = g∗a + Gd*(1−a);
double result_b = b∗a + Bd*(1−a);
double result_a = a∗a + Ad*(1−a);
```

It works fine if the destination image is opaque. But I need transparent Images on both source and destination. Are there any other calculation methods or functions of OpenCV?

Regards

Comment: Please check my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73498765/2299100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the cvFunction `addWeighted()`. It performs what you need
Here is the [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems that the `addWeighted()` function takes same alpha values for all pixels. Can I apply different alpha values owned by src1 and src2 for each pixels?

Comment: No, it is not possible with addWeighted(). You could initialize the mat element and use multiply().
But, if my previous answer works for your first question, mark it as an accepted answer