# WebGL alpha blending

Tags: glsl, webgl, alphablending, blending

I'm trying to layer one texture over another, but I'm having alpha blending issues around the edges. I've tried many blending combinations with no luck. Where am I going wrong?

Current state of framebuffer (opaque):

[image]

Transparent texture rendered in off-screen framebuffer:

[image]

Result when I try to blend the two. Notice the edges on the circle:

[image]

Here's the blendFunc:

```
_gl.blendFuncSeparate( _gl.SRC_ALPHA, _gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, _gl.ONE, _gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
```

Here's the shader. Just basic rendering of a texture:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec4 tColor = texture2D(texture, vUv);

    gl_FragColor = tColor;
}
```

Comment: Please check my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73498765/2299100

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your textures are using premultiplied alpha and so your blend function should be

```
_gl.blendFunc(_gl.ONE, _gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

If your textures are not premultiplied you probably want to premultiply them either in your shader

```
gl_FragColor.rgb *= gl_FragColor.a
```

or when you load them (before you call `gl.texImage2D`) you can tell the browser to premultiply them

```
_gl.pixelStorei(_gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);
```

[This document probably explains the issues better](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre)

and you might find this relevant as well

[WebGL: How to correctly blend alpha channel png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341564/webgl-how-to-correctly-blend-alpha-channel-png/)